# Python plus-equals operator that prepends

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

Is there a variation of the Python `+=` operator that prepends instead of appending?

I.e. `x += 'text'`, but instead of `x+'text'`, `'text'+x`.

**Edit:**

I am trying to make a command line in part of a program and I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 15, in <module>
    a[0] = 'control/'+a[0]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Code snippet:

`a = a.split()`

```
# Command Line
    if (a[0][0:1] == '!') and (len(a[0]) > 1):
      a = a[0][1:] # remove evoker
      if a == 'quit': break
      else:
        try:
          a[0] += 'control/'+a[0]
          subprocess.call(a)
        except:
          print("That is not a valid command.")
```

Comment: " I get a TypeError" -- then `x` must not be a string. Maybe it's `bytes`.

Comment: Yes, x is a string (It is in a list).

Comment: You want to "prepend" an element to a list?  You should ask that question then:  `x.insert(0, 'text')`

Comment: If you used your own class, you could define your very special increment operation implementing/overriding `__iadd__`

Comment: @Mark No, I want to prepend text to a list item. That is, `x` (or rather `x[n]`) is an item in a list.

Comment: @Krii: strings in Python are immutable, so if you want to change (say) the first item in a list named `li`, then you need to do `li[0] = 'text' + li[0]`. I still don't understand how you got that `TypeError`, since if the variable `x` is a string then you *definitely* will not get a `TypeError` from `x = 'text' + x`. If you do want any advice on that you'll have to show the code.

Comment: @SteveJessop which gives me the TypeError. As I said in the question.

Comment: @Krii: not on my machine. Show the code or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Krii As Steve said, this should not happen when x is a string. I'd `print(type(x))` just to be sure.

Comment: `li = ['bar']; li[0] = 'foo' + li[0]; print(li)` -- result is `['foobar']` and no `TypeError`.

Comment: @Takis returns `<class 'str'>`

Comment: Initially `a` is a string. `a = a.split()` means it's a list. `a = a[0][1:]` means it's back to being a string again. Then `a[0] = ` throws the error because strings are immutable. You probably meant `a = 'control/' + a`. Top tip: you're allowed more than one variable ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop That turned out to be a coding error (forgot to add `[0]` at end). The problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a solution to what you are looking for.

If you used your own class, you could define your very special increment operation overriding `__iadd__`:

```
class My_str(str):
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return other+self

ms = My_str('hello')
ms += 'world'
print(ms)
```

produces

```
worldhello
```

So with such elements in a list you could do something like

```
>>> l = [My_str(i) for i in range(5)]
>>> l[1] += 'text'
>>> l
['0', 'text1', '2', '3', '4']
```

All comments are welcome.

Comment: I will accept this because it is relevant to the question (as it turns out, the question wasn't my problem).

Comment: @Krii But my 7 word answer technically answered the question

Answer (score 3):

No there is not a prepend operator.